# Calculate distances between polygon centres in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, distance

Is there a practical way to calculate distances between polygon centroids in QGIS? I have a UK city region map divided into administrative units (1 ward = 1 polygon). I want to represent their population growth in function of the distance to the core city and the best way to do it seems to be looking for the geometrical 'centroid' of each polygon and measure its distance to the 'centroid' of the core city polygon. I can do it manually with the ruler tool but it takes a long time and is not very accurate.
Thanks

Comment: I do not have time to write a full answer, but... Have a look into realcentroid plugin for creating the centroids, and Vector > Analysis tools > Matrix distance fro measuring all distances.

Answer (score 2):

As Alexandre wrote, it is relatively easy - You want centroids and distance matrix. But I will additionaly suggest that You will use two algorithms from `Processing` plugin:

```
1) SAGA > Polygon centroids
```

and then

```
2) SAGA > Distance matrix
```

Both can save results to temporary file which is helpful, especially for centroids.